# Open dialog at a certain amount of launches of the Flutter App

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have an App and i want it to open a dialog after the user launched the app 5 times. How can i make it possible?

The package I'm using to open the dialog is [in_app_review](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_review).

```
import 'package:in_app_review/in_app_review.dart';

final InAppReview inAppReview = InAppReview.instance;

 if(userHasLaunchedAppFiveTimes){ 
      if (await inAppReview.isAvailable()) {
         inAppReview.requestReview();
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use persistent storage to achieve this. You can use this package: [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)
Use the below code to increment `nbTimesLaunched` each time user launches app.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
int nbTimesLaunched = (prefs.getInt('nbTimesLaunched') ?? 0) + 1;
await prefs.setInt('nbTimesLaunched', nbTimesLaunched);
```

And then when you want to show the dialog:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
int nbTimesLaunched = prefs.getInt('nbTimesLaunched') ?? 1;
if (nbTimesLaunched == 5) {
    // show dialogue
}
```

**UPDATE**

You can just put the first part where you increment the count inside main. make sure to call the `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` or else you'll get an error.

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  int nbTimesLaunched = (prefs.getInt('nbTimesLaunched') ?? 0) + 1;
  await prefs.setInt('nbTimesLaunched', nbTimesLaunched);
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But where should i put this code?

Comment: @maruthan The first part you can just put inside main. I've updated my answer to show that. The second part just put wherever you want to show the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Use https://pub.dev/packages/advanced_in_app_review . It does exactly what you are searching for. Its build on top of in_app_review and gives you some options to display only after some time / days a.s.o.